# why such a difference in file contents C#

Tags: c#

My intention is to write a `byte[]` to a file. Code snippet is below:

```
byte[] stream = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 60 };

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    FileStream aCmdFileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\binarydata.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    StreamWriter aStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(aCmdFileStream);

    for (int ii = 0; ii < stream.Length; ii++)
    {
        aStreamWriter.Write(stream[ii]);
        aStreamWriter.WriteLine(); 
        aStreamWriter.BaseStream.Write(stream,0,stream.Length);
    }

    aStreamWriter.Close();
}
```

Output of this code snippet

```
(<
(<
(<
(<
(<10
20
30
40
60

(<
(<
(<
(<
(<10
20
30
40
60
```

When `StreamWriter.Write()` is used it dumps the values which are stored in array. But `StreamWriter.BaseStream.Write(byte[],int offset, int length)`, the values are totally different. What is the reason for this?

Comment: I would suggest you not to use classes that are meant for working with text (like `StreamWriter`) to work with binary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `StreamWriter` is a `TextWriter` and converts the bytes to Text (string representation).

And using  `BaseStream.Write(byte[] data, ...)` directly writes the bytes without any conversion.

But you are using the 2 methods interleaved, I guess some overwriting is happening too. Note that you should use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `StreamWriter` is buffering (not expecting anyone to directly access the `BaseStream`), which is why the numbers are appearing after the other text.

Comment: just curious to know why such special characters are generated, bytes means a value from 0 to 255.

Comment: Re the 'special chars' - what you see depends on the viewer used and what encoding is used/deduced.